# I need a small hint... 'string index out of range python module'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I know that it is very weird code, but try not to pay attention. I just want to solve this task with such a strange method. But in the process, I am faced with this problem. Can you help me to fix it?

```
in <module>
   in reverse_alternate
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I suppose that it's associated with modulo. Right?

---

```
def reverse_alternate(string):
    a = string.split(' ')
    new = ''
    for i, c in enumerate(a):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            new += ' ' + c[::-1] + ' '
        else:
            new += c

    if new[-1] == ' ':
        a = new[:-1]
        return a
    else:
        return new
```

Comment: what should this function do?

Comment: task: 'Reverse every other word in the string' 
Test.assert_equals(reverse_alternate("I really hope it works this time..."), "I yllaer hope ti works siht time...")

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if new[-1] == ' ':
```

with

```
if len(new) and new[-1] == ' ':
```

If you have no tokens, `new` will end up being empty, and as such, it won't have the -1'st element. Thus, referencing it would result in "index out of range" error.